# How to use argv[1] as a predefined macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

[Coding in POSIX, using Geany in Ubuntu]

I have these classes: **main.c**, **A.c**, **A.h** where A.h is included in main.c. I started all my project using a macro in A.c, namely `#define PNUM 10`. I already defined structures, several arrays, I created threads and so on and eventually when I got everything done, I decided to ask the user to enter an integer as `PNUM` using `argv` in main.c file. (`PNUM` determines the number of **threads** that I'm going to deal with.)

- I don't want to pass this value to A.c file using functions in main.c:
  I tried so but it's my first experience in POSIX and the level of difficulty went over my knowledge.
- I know that `#define PNUM 10` is a symbolic name to numeric constants and cannot be reassigned at all. I also don't insist on keeping this line of my code, however, it seems crucial here.(e.g creating `PNUM` number of threads in initialization step and allocating memory to arrays of condition variables, etc.)
- My question seems to have an easy and straightforward answer but I am not very comfortable with **C**.

---

The general scheme: All functions mentioned in A.c need to know PNUM.

### main.c

```
#include "philos.h"

void* philosopher(int *);
void* waiter(int *);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int philNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    void * tab = tableinit(philosopher, waiter);
    return 0;
}

void * philosopher(int * who)
{   ...
    pickup((*who));
    putdown((*who));
    ...
}
void * waiter(int * who)
{   ...
    replaceBottles();
    refillBowls();
    ...
}
```

---

### A.c

```
#define PNUM 10
#define WAITERNUM 2
typedef struct tablestruct
{
    pthread_t t[PNUM];
    pthread_t w[WAITERNUM];
    int self[PNUM];
    int wself[WAITERNUM];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition[PNUM];
    philstat status[PNUM];
    int snack_wine[PNUM];
 }table;
void printstate(){...}
void pickup(int k){...}
void putdown(int k){...}
int test (int i){...}
int consumptions(int i){...}
int finishedServing(int){...}
void replaceBottles(int){...}
void refillBowls(int){...}
table * tableinit(void *(* philosopher)(void *), void*(* waiter)(void *)){...}
```

Comment: You could make it a global variable, but you would need to convert it from a character array to an integer, and it is generally a poor design choice.  You will need to learn to pass parameters at some point, might as well learn now.  If you are having specific trouble with that then you could ask a question about your specific code here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The problem is that,in main.c, I call one function taking 2 functions as its arguments, either of them calls several other functions. Each of above mentioned functions has to pass this PNUM, if this is the strategy. Not only it seems dirty coding, but also it adds a great proportion to my code which seems not neat.

Comment: As an alternative, wherever these functions need to know the number of threads, they could call a function getPnum(), which returns a variable. And the user-input sets said variable.

Comment: Without seeing an example of your code it's hard to comment on specifics, but it sounds like a troublesome design from the beginning and it's likely you would need to restructure things to make it cleaner, or look for a bandaid and hope it doesn't cause more trouble in the future.

Comment: macros are text replacement operations, that are handled in the pre-processor, so are non existent at run time.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I just added the main idea of my code. (To be clear: I need argv[1] work in place of PNUM.)

Answer (score 2):

The question as it stands doesn't quite work. You can't take user input and use it as a macro. You know this: "...numeric constants and cannot be reassigned". As in, it's never going to be anything other than 10.

So if you want the number of threads to vary depending on user-input, you're not going to be able to use a macro.

I mean, you could do something lame like `#define PNUM global_num_threads` or '#define PNUM getNumThreads()`, and add a global or a function to go get that variable. While that might be the.... least intrusive into your codebase, it's a bad design that indicates rot. If you're going to make this sort of change to the code, do it right.

Yeah, even though it "seems crucial" to use a macro, it's not. You can swap that out with a variable.

And passing variables is almost fundamental, so get used to it.

Comment: It's possible that he has declared some data structures as a statically allocated array sized to the number - fixing this would require a more thorough redesign of his code.

Comment: Yes, it would. And if he wants users to set the number of threads, or for the number of threads to be anything other than 10, he will most certainly have to do that.

Comment: @Random832 and Philip your both guesses are right. I have data structure containing arrays and variable number of threads must be created.